# In which circumstances is the identity of a miner known?

Tags: miner-configuration, identity

I started playing with the [Blockchain real-time API](https://blockchain.info/api/api_websocket) and noticed that when new blocks were created, they often (systematically?) included a `foundBy` field. For instance, block with height [446731](https://blockchain.info/block/00000000000000000040192da1a87b61cfd6a74221304cd1e73ea30b9ca8303f) (index 1442483) has the following `foundBy` information:

```
{
    "ip": "0.0.0.0",
    "link": "http://bitfury.com/",
    "description": "BitFury", 
    "time": 1483612060
}
```

I have never mined bitcoins; do all miners have to disclose their identity? Obviously, the identity of the miner of block with height 0 is unknown. Is the `foundBy` field a new feature of recently-mined blocks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not necessary to disclose the identity. As Pieter commented below, "`foundBy` is a feature of blockchain.info, a privately operated website, which gives a guess about the creator of a block. It is by no means something that's part of the protocol".

If you look at the receiving [address](https://blockchain.info/de/address/1DrK44np3gMKuvcGeFVv9Jk67zodP52eMu) of the block's coinbase, you'll see that BitFury sends all their block rewards to that address, so that's probably how blockchain.info arrived at their conclusion.

Comment: To answer the asked question: foundBy is a feature of blockchain.info, a privately operated website, which gives a guess about the creator of a block. It is by no means something that's part of the protocol.